# Remove Elements From AJAX Result

Tags: jquery, arrays

[Here are my Codes](http://jsfiddle.net/5Yj8g/1/) ... I want to remove Elements that are listed in "`removeElements`" array if they exist.
so i made a loop through that array.
If that array starts with element which exists in variable X everything works fine. like :

```
var removeElements = new Array(".cindymenubar", ".menu", ".drop-menu-layout", ".right-menu", ".menu-box", "#nav", "#MainHMenu", "#MainVMenu", ".slide-menu-layout");
```

but if it start with element that doesn't used in variable X `null` will return

Comment: Did you try this : `$(removeElements.join(",")).remove();` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    $.each(removeElements, function(index, val) {
       $(x).remove(val);
    });
```

**OR:**

```
     var TempHTML = $('<div/>').html(x);
     $(removeElments.join(', '), TempHTML).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Variable that holds Html returns from ajax onsuccess callback
            var x = "<div id='SB_ContentsBlock_seo' class='SB_ContentsBlock'>  <!--@SBML_SEO--><h1>Testing</h1><br />  <div class='SB_ContentsBlockHolder'>Testing For Remove Elements From AJAX Result </div></div>    <div class='cindycontent'>  <div class='cindyheader'>  <div class='cindybanner'>  <div id='SB_ContentsBlock_banner'>  <!--@SBML_BANNER-->  </div>  </div>  <div class='cindylogo'>  <div id='SB_ContentsBlock_paragraph01' class='SB_ContentsBlock'>  <!--@SBML_PARAGRAPH01-->  <div class='SB_ContentsBlockHolder'> </div></div>  </div>  </div>  <div class='cindymenubar'><ul style='display:none;' id='MainHMenu'><li><a href='index.html' target='_self'><p>خانه</p></a><ul><li><a href='orderproduct.html' target='_self'><p>فرم سفارش محصول</p></a></li></ul></li><li><a href='contact.html' target='_self'><p>تماس با ما</p></a></li><li><a href='artciles_sub3.html' target='_self'><p>تست منو</p></a><ul><li><a href='nTest.html' target='_self'><p>آزمايشي</p></a><div class='sitebaansubmenuarrow'></div><ul><li><a href='nTest2.html' target='_self'><p>تست</p></a></li><li><a href='page.html' target='_self'><p>تست 2</p></a><div class='sitebaansubmenuarrow'></div><ul><li><a href='mainpagebank.html' target='_self'><p>تست3</p></a></li></ul></li><li><a href='testpage2.html' target='_self'><p>صفحه آزمايشي2</p></a><div class='sitebaansubmenuarrow'></div><ul><li><a href='javascript:void(0)' style='cursor:default;'><p>هويج</p></a></li><li><a href='testpage.html' target='_self'><p>صفحه آزمايشي 3</p></a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href='articles.html' target='_self'><p>مقالات</p></a><div class='sitebaansubmenuarrow'></div><ul><li><a href='modules_test.html' target='_self'><p>ماژول ها</p></a><div class='sitebaansubmenuarrow'></div><ul><li><a href='newsmod.html' target='_self'><p>ماژول اخبار</p></a></li><li><a href='productsmod.html' target='_self'><p>ماژول محصولات</p></a></li></ul></li><li><a href='articles_sub.html' target='_self'><p>زير صفحه مقالات</p></a><div class='sitebaansubmenuarrow'></div><ul><li><a href='faq.html' target='_self'><p>سوال و جواب</p></a></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href='memberspage.html' target='_self'><p>صفحات اعضا</p></a><ul><li><a href='signinusers.html' target='_self'><p>ورود و خروج اعضاء</p></a><div class='sitebaansubmenuarrow'></div><ul></ul></li><li><a href='msginbox.html' target='_self'><p>صندوق پيامها</p></a></li><li><a href='0000000.html' target='_self'><p>Inbox</p></a></li><li><a href='signupsite.html' target='_self'><p>عضويت در سايت</p></a><div class='sitebaansubmenuarrow'></div><ul></ul></li><li><a href='memberssearch.html' target='_self'><p>جستجوي اعضاء</p></a></li><li><a href='profileedit.html' target='_self'><p>ويرايش پروفايل</p></a></li><li><a href='tetstetst.html' target='_self'><p>ليست اعضاء</p></a><div class='sitebaansubmenuarrow'></div><ul><li><a href='menuchildtest.html' target='_self'><p>تست زير صفحه منو</p></a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href='fruitlist.html' target='_self'><p>ميوه فروشي</p></a><ul><li><a href='viewbill.html' target='_self'><p>نمايش صورت حساب</p></a></li><li><a href='mybasket.html' target='_self'><p>سبد خريد</p></a></li></ul></li><li><a href='mypagessss.html' target='_self'><p>صفحه من</p></a><ul><li><a href='templatetest.html' target='_self'><p>تست قالب</p></a></li></ul></li><li><a href='showarticles.html' target='_self'><p>نمايش مقلات</p></a></li><li><a href='formcontact.html' target='_self'><p>فرم</p></a><ul><li><a href='filmorder.html' target='_self'><p>سفارش فيلم</p></a></li><li><a href='adv_form.html' target='_self'><p>فرم ساز پيشرفته</p></a></li></ul></li><li><a href='myhavij.html' target='_self'><p>هويج</p></a><ul><li><a href='continue2.html' target='_self'><p>دنباله دوم</p></a></li><li><a href='continue3.html' target='_self'><p>دنباله سوم</p></a></li></ul></li><li><a href='hesabi.html' target='_self'><p>حسابي</p></a><ul><li><a href='subbpage.html' target='_self'><p>زيرصفحه</p></a></li><li><a href='test_hesabi.html' target='_self'><p>test</p></a></li></ul></li></ul>      </div>  <div class='cindypagecontent'>  <div class='cindyleft'>  <div id='SB_ContentsBlock_paragraphleft' class='SB_ContentsBlock'>  <!--@SBML_PARAGRAPHLEFT-->  <div class='SB_ContentsBlockHolder'> </div></div>  </div>  <div class='cindymodules'>        <div id='SB_ContentsBlock_contentpane' class='SB_ContentsBlock'>  <!--PRID 1931-->    <div id='SB_Paragraph_1931'  style='  clear:both;  width: 98%; border-style: solid; border-color: #000000; border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px ; float: none; margin: 3px 3px 10px 3px; padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;'>  <div class='SB_Paragraph_Content'></div>    <div style='direction:inherit;width:100%;background-color:transparent; border:0px solid #E2E2E2;'>    <table style='border-collapse: collapse;width:100%;'>  <tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  1  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=i6b1g4i5006e&cntid=2649'>  هدايت الله درياني  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>mbarzi@gmail.com</td>  <td>2,230,002,000</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/12/08</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  2  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=p5i9n4p5006e&cntid=2649'>  باباشاه  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>babashah@msn.com</td>  <td>445,003,660</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/20</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  3  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=h7y2f6h6006e&cntid=2649'>  ايمان محمدي  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>credo61@gmail.com</td>  <td>220,033,666</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/10</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  4  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=c7u2z5c6006e&cntid=2649'>  زرطزر  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>mbarzi@gmail.com</td>  <td>طزرطزر</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/10</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  5  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=g4y8e2g3006e&cntid=2649'>  نادر نيکفر  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>mbarzi@gmail.com</td>  <td>1,422,222</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/10</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  6  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=n3f7l1n2006e&cntid=2649'>  کوروش نعمتي  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>mbarzi@gmail.com</td>  <td>9,123,182,230</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/10</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  7  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=m3e7k1m2006e&cntid=2649'>  ليلا شبستري  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>mbarzi@gmail.com</td>  <td>2,558,833,699</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/10</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  8  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=w3o7u1w2006e&cntid=2649'>  رحيم مشايي  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>rahim@msn.com</td>  <td>9,123,182,230</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/10</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  9  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=p2h6m9p1006e&cntid=2649'>  صبورچي  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>saboorchi@pic.ir</td>  <td>2,203,366,666</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/10</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  10  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=oof6o4dn006e&cntid=2649'>  يدالله تارنتينو  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>yadolah.tarentno@gmail.com</td>  <td>2,358,222,000</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/10</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  11  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=jilb5bv4006e&cntid=2649'>  احسان سميعي  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>ehsan@yahoo.com</td>  <td>33,253,690</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/09</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  12  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=96xd6y9g006e&cntid=2649'>  حسن کچل  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>hasankachal@yahoo.com</td>  <td>25,500,366</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/09</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  13  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=7lyc81ns006e&cntid=2649'>  جوليا اندرسون  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>julia@yahoo.com</td>  <td>225,522,200</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/07</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  14  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=nne5n3cl006e&cntid=2649'>  رها اعتمادي  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>raha@yahoo.com</td>  <td>2,522,336,666</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/07</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  15  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=ff6wgu3e006e&cntid=2649'>  حسن حسني  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>hasan@yaahoo.com</td>  <td>2,253,231,321</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/06</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  16  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=kimc6cw5006e&cntid=2649'>  سيم سيم  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>simsim@yahoo.com</td>  <td>654,456,464</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/06</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  17  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=srj9s8hq006e&cntid=2649'>  جورابيان  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>joorabian@yahoo.com</td>  <td>2,503,300</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/06</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  18  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=om2iy2z8006e&cntid=2649'>  تينا رحماني  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>tina@yahoo.com</td>  <td>91,250,032,009</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/06</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  19  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=clz18fcv006e&cntid=2649'>  ايمان محمدي  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>credo61@asd.com</td>  <td>sdf</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/04</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  20  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=wvyoko9j006e&cntid=2649'>  عباس  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>abbas@msn.com</td>  <td>145,000,036</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/04</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    </tr>    <tr>  <td colspan='1'>    <div align='center'>  <table class='mgpagecount' style='border-collapse:collapse; background-color:Transparent; color:#000000;font:11px Tahoma; font-weight:300;'>    <tr>  <td>    <span style='filter: alpha(opacity=40); opacity: 0.4;cursor:default;'>صفحه قبل</span>    </td>  <td><span>| 1</span> / <span>2 |</span></td>  <td>    <a style='text-decoration: none;color:#000000;' href='?page=2&'>صفحه بعد</a>    </td>  </tr>    </table>  </div>    </td>  </tr>    </table>    </div>      </div>    <!--PRID 1931 END-->  <!--@SBML_CONTENTPANE-->  <div class='SB_ContentsBlockHolder'> </div></div>      </div>  <div class='cindyright'>    <div id='SB_ContentsBlock_paragraphright' class='SB_ContentsBlock'>  <!--@SBML_PARAGRAPHRIGHT-->  <div class='SB_ContentsBlockHolder'> </div></div>    <ul style='display:none;' id='MainVMenu'><li><a href='orderproduct.html' target='_self'><p>فرم سفارش محصول</p></a></li></ul>        </div>  </div>    <div class='cindycopyright'>  <div id='SB_ContentsBlock_copyright'>  <!--@SBML_COPYRIGHT-->  </div>  </div>  </div>";

            var TempHTML = $(x).remove('.cindymenubar, .menu, .drop-menu-layout, .right-menu, .menu-box, #nav, #MainHMenu, #MainVMenu, .slide-menu-layout').html();

            $('body').html(TempHTML);
        });  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var removeElements = new Array(".cindymenubar", ".menu", ".drop-menu-layout", ".right-menu", ".menu-box", "#nav", "#MainHMenu", "#MainVMenu", ".slide-menu-layout");

            //Variable that holds Html returns from ajax onsuccess callback
            var x = "<div id='SB_ContentsBlock_seo' class='SB_ContentsBlock'>  <!--@SBML_SEO--><h1>Testing</h1><br />  <div class='SB_ContentsBlockHolder'>Testing For Remove Elements From AJAX Result </div></div>    <div class='cindycontent'>  <div class='cindyheader'>  <div class='cindybanner'>  <div id='SB_ContentsBlock_banner'>  <!--@SBML_BANNER-->  </div>  </div>  <div class='cindylogo'>  <div id='SB_ContentsBlock_paragraph01' class='SB_ContentsBlock'>  <!--@SBML_PARAGRAPH01-->  <div class='SB_ContentsBlockHolder'> </div></div>  </div>  </div>  <div class='cindymenubar'><ul style='display:none;' id='MainHMenu'><li><a href='index.html' target='_self'><p>خانه</p></a><ul><li><a href='orderproduct.html' target='_self'><p>فرم سفارش محصول</p></a></li></ul></li><li><a href='contact.html' target='_self'><p>تماس با ما</p></a></li><li><a href='artciles_sub3.html' target='_self'><p>تست منو</p></a><ul><li><a href='nTest.html' target='_self'><p>آزمايشي</p></a><div class='sitebaansubmenuarrow'></div><ul><li><a href='nTest2.html' target='_self'><p>تست</p></a></li><li><a href='page.html' target='_self'><p>تست 2</p></a><div class='sitebaansubmenuarrow'></div><ul><li><a href='mainpagebank.html' target='_self'><p>تست3</p></a></li></ul></li><li><a href='testpage2.html' target='_self'><p>صفحه آزمايشي2</p></a><div class='sitebaansubmenuarrow'></div><ul><li><a href='javascript:void(0)' style='cursor:default;'><p>هويج</p></a></li><li><a href='testpage.html' target='_self'><p>صفحه آزمايشي 3</p></a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href='articles.html' target='_self'><p>مقالات</p></a><div class='sitebaansubmenuarrow'></div><ul><li><a href='modules_test.html' target='_self'><p>ماژول ها</p></a><div class='sitebaansubmenuarrow'></div><ul><li><a href='newsmod.html' target='_self'><p>ماژول اخبار</p></a></li><li><a href='productsmod.html' target='_self'><p>ماژول محصولات</p></a></li></ul></li><li><a href='articles_sub.html' target='_self'><p>زير صفحه مقالات</p></a><div class='sitebaansubmenuarrow'></div><ul><li><a href='faq.html' target='_self'><p>سوال و جواب</p></a></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href='memberspage.html' target='_self'><p>صفحات اعضا</p></a><ul><li><a href='signinusers.html' target='_self'><p>ورود و خروج اعضاء</p></a><div class='sitebaansubmenuarrow'></div><ul></ul></li><li><a href='msginbox.html' target='_self'><p>صندوق پيامها</p></a></li><li><a href='0000000.html' target='_self'><p>Inbox</p></a></li><li><a href='signupsite.html' target='_self'><p>عضويت در سايت</p></a><div class='sitebaansubmenuarrow'></div><ul></ul></li><li><a href='memberssearch.html' target='_self'><p>جستجوي اعضاء</p></a></li><li><a href='profileedit.html' target='_self'><p>ويرايش پروفايل</p></a></li><li><a href='tetstetst.html' target='_self'><p>ليست اعضاء</p></a><div class='sitebaansubmenuarrow'></div><ul><li><a href='menuchildtest.html' target='_self'><p>تست زير صفحه منو</p></a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href='fruitlist.html' target='_self'><p>ميوه فروشي</p></a><ul><li><a href='viewbill.html' target='_self'><p>نمايش صورت حساب</p></a></li><li><a href='mybasket.html' target='_self'><p>سبد خريد</p></a></li></ul></li><li><a href='mypagessss.html' target='_self'><p>صفحه من</p></a><ul><li><a href='templatetest.html' target='_self'><p>تست قالب</p></a></li></ul></li><li><a href='showarticles.html' target='_self'><p>نمايش مقلات</p></a></li><li><a href='formcontact.html' target='_self'><p>فرم</p></a><ul><li><a href='filmorder.html' target='_self'><p>سفارش فيلم</p></a></li><li><a href='adv_form.html' target='_self'><p>فرم ساز پيشرفته</p></a></li></ul></li><li><a href='myhavij.html' target='_self'><p>هويج</p></a><ul><li><a href='continue2.html' target='_self'><p>دنباله دوم</p></a></li><li><a href='continue3.html' target='_self'><p>دنباله سوم</p></a></li></ul></li><li><a href='hesabi.html' target='_self'><p>حسابي</p></a><ul><li><a href='subbpage.html' target='_self'><p>زيرصفحه</p></a></li><li><a href='test_hesabi.html' target='_self'><p>test</p></a></li></ul></li></ul>      </div>  <div class='cindypagecontent'>  <div class='cindyleft'>  <div id='SB_ContentsBlock_paragraphleft' class='SB_ContentsBlock'>  <!--@SBML_PARAGRAPHLEFT-->  <div class='SB_ContentsBlockHolder'> </div></div>  </div>  <div class='cindymodules'>        <div id='SB_ContentsBlock_contentpane' class='SB_ContentsBlock'>  <!--PRID 1931-->    <div id='SB_Paragraph_1931'  style='  clear:both;  width: 98%; border-style: solid; border-color: #000000; border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px ; float: none; margin: 3px 3px 10px 3px; padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;'>  <div class='SB_Paragraph_Content'></div>    <div style='direction:inherit;width:100%;background-color:transparent; border:0px solid #E2E2E2;'>    <table style='border-collapse: collapse;width:100%;'>  <tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  1  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=i6b1g4i5006e&cntid=2649'>  هدايت الله درياني  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>mbarzi@gmail.com</td>  <td>2,230,002,000</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/12/08</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  2  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=p5i9n4p5006e&cntid=2649'>  باباشاه  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>babashah@msn.com</td>  <td>445,003,660</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/20</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  3  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=h7y2f6h6006e&cntid=2649'>  ايمان محمدي  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>credo61@gmail.com</td>  <td>220,033,666</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/10</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  4  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=c7u2z5c6006e&cntid=2649'>  زرطزر  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>mbarzi@gmail.com</td>  <td>طزرطزر</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/10</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  5  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=g4y8e2g3006e&cntid=2649'>  نادر نيکفر  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>mbarzi@gmail.com</td>  <td>1,422,222</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/10</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  6  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=n3f7l1n2006e&cntid=2649'>  کوروش نعمتي  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>mbarzi@gmail.com</td>  <td>9,123,182,230</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/10</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  7  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=m3e7k1m2006e&cntid=2649'>  ليلا شبستري  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>mbarzi@gmail.com</td>  <td>2,558,833,699</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/10</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  8  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=w3o7u1w2006e&cntid=2649'>  رحيم مشايي  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>rahim@msn.com</td>  <td>9,123,182,230</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/10</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  9  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=p2h6m9p1006e&cntid=2649'>  صبورچي  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>saboorchi@pic.ir</td>  <td>2,203,366,666</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/10</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  10  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=oof6o4dn006e&cntid=2649'>  يدالله تارنتينو  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>yadolah.tarentno@gmail.com</td>  <td>2,358,222,000</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/10</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  11  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=jilb5bv4006e&cntid=2649'>  احسان سميعي  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>ehsan@yahoo.com</td>  <td>33,253,690</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/09</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  12  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=96xd6y9g006e&cntid=2649'>  حسن کچل  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>hasankachal@yahoo.com</td>  <td>25,500,366</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/09</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  13  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=7lyc81ns006e&cntid=2649'>  جوليا اندرسون  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>julia@yahoo.com</td>  <td>225,522,200</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/07</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  14  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=nne5n3cl006e&cntid=2649'>  رها اعتمادي  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>raha@yahoo.com</td>  <td>2,522,336,666</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/07</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  15  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=ff6wgu3e006e&cntid=2649'>  حسن حسني  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>hasan@yaahoo.com</td>  <td>2,253,231,321</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/06</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  16  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=kimc6cw5006e&cntid=2649'>  سيم سيم  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>simsim@yahoo.com</td>  <td>654,456,464</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/06</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  17  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=srj9s8hq006e&cntid=2649'>  جورابيان  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>joorabian@yahoo.com</td>  <td>2,503,300</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/06</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  18  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=om2iy2z8006e&cntid=2649'>  تينا رحماني  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>tina@yahoo.com</td>  <td>91,250,032,009</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/06</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  19  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=clz18fcv006e&cntid=2649'>  ايمان محمدي  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>credo61@asd.com</td>  <td>sdf</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/04</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    <td style='padding:0px;width:100%;'>      <table class='mymgreport'  style='width:100%;'>  <tr>  <td style='width:20px;border-right:3px solid #a7c6eb;'>  20  </td>  <td style='width:150px;'>  <a href='?m=mg&mc=showdetails&m_id=wvyoko9j006e&cntid=2649'>  عباس  </a>  </td>  <td style='width:150px'>abbas@msn.com</td>  <td>145,000,036</td>  <td>@@MG:HAVIJ@@</td>  <td>1389/11/04</td>  </tr>  </table>          </td></tr><tr>    </tr>    <tr>  <td colspan='1'>    <div align='center'>  <table class='mgpagecount' style='border-collapse:collapse; background-color:Transparent; color:#000000;font:11px Tahoma; font-weight:300;'>    <tr>  <td>    <span style='filter: alpha(opacity=40); opacity: 0.4;cursor:default;'>صفحه قبل</span>    </td>  <td><span>| 1</span> / <span>2 |</span></td>  <td>    <a style='text-decoration: none;color:#000000;' href='?page=2&'>صفحه بعد</a>    </td>  </tr>    </table>  </div>    </td>  </tr>    </table>    </div>      </div>    <!--PRID 1931 END-->  <!--@SBML_CONTENTPANE-->  <div class='SB_ContentsBlockHolder'> </div></div>      </div>  <div class='cindyright'>    <div id='SB_ContentsBlock_paragraphright' class='SB_ContentsBlock'>  <!--@SBML_PARAGRAPHRIGHT-->  <div class='SB_ContentsBlockHolder'> </div></div>    <ul style='display:none;' id='MainVMenu'><li><a href='orderproduct.html' target='_self'><p>فرم سفارش محصول</p></a></li></ul>        </div>  </div>    <div class='cindycopyright'>  <div id='SB_ContentsBlock_copyright'>  <!--@SBML_COPYRIGHT-->  </div>  </div>  </div>";

            var TempHTML = $(x).remove(removeElements.join(',')).html();

            $('body').html(TempHTML);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```